# Bash script to launch chromium, sleep for 20 seconds, then close quietly

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash script that will launch chromium, wait 20 seconds, then close chromium.

This is for xbmcbuntu so I can open a site, then it will close automatically after 20 seconds (as I will have no way of closing it with just the remote control).

What I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
openbox &
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
sleep 20
killall -9 openbox
```

Chromium opens ok, but never closes.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not putting chromium-browser in the background, none of the code after the chromium-browser command will execute until chromium-browser finishes execution. This should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
openbox &
openbox_pid=$!
/usr/bin/chromium-browser &
chrome_pid=$!
sleep 20
kill "$chrome_pid" "$openbox_pid"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of killing `openbox`, you need to kill `chromium-browser`.

```
openbox &
openbox_pid=$!
/usr/bin/chromium-browser &
chromium_pid=$!
sleep 20
kill $chromium_pid
kill $openbox_pid
```

Don't use `kill -9` unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, only my idea

`#`!/bin/bash
openbox &

here run: script.any &    #background where script.any permission is execute and contain:
`#`!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/chromium-browser

## from this script run browser show mode

sleep 20
killall -9 openbox

sorry my bad english
Anjoy ;)